# how to print random string in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = ['hello','chicken','world']

import random

a = random(a)
print (a) #trying to print them in random order.
```

how would I print them in random order? It gives me a error: "Type Error: 'module' object is not callable". Also would it be possible to print a word from the list and then ask the user what comes next? and check if the user got it right and continue through the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because your calling `random` which is a module and not a method. You probably want
to call `random.choice` see [random.choice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`random.shuffle()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to shuffle your list in place. For example

```
>>> a = ['hello','chicken','world']
>>> import random
>>> a
['hello', 'chicken', 'world']
>>> random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
['chicken', 'world', 'hello']
>>> random.shuffle(a)
>>> a
['hello', 'world', 'chicken']
```

Comment: My programs seems to print 'chicken , 'hello', 'world'. every time i try print (a) it prints the same variable. How would i make it random each time.

Comment: @user2980929 This is after you use `random.shuffle(a)`? Note it shuffles *in place*, so you don't need to have `a = random.shuffle(a)` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 
a = ['hello','chicken','world']

random.shuffle(a)

print "first element is %s" %a[0]
for i in a[1:]:
    guess = str(raw_input("Guess next item:")).strip()
    if guess == i:
        print "Correct"
    else:
        print "Wrong it was: %s" %i
```